# Is there a way to have multiple layers in Processing?

Tags: processing, layer

Is there a way to have multiple layers in Processing ?

Each layer would have its own setup/draw context.

Comment: You mean multiple windows?

Comment: nope, PGraphics isn't window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sort of. Consider using [`PGraphics`](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) (essentially buffered, independent canvases). You can then manipulate your images inside each PGraphic, making each the size of the screen (forming layers), or move the PGraphics about the screen as objects. [Here's](http://forum.processing.org/topic/run-methods-on-a-layer-created-by-pgraphics) a place you might start.

Comment: Yes, that's a known problem with these. There is a way to remove the cache. Look [here](http://forum.processing.org/topic/how-to-deal-with-memory-issues)

Comment: cannot figure out what the "g" is in "g.removeCache(img);"
Is it the instance of the applet?

Comment: `g` is not a variable declared in the program, it is part of the core.jar library. Pardon my very approximate explanation, but roughly speaking it's a way to access the underlying `Graphics` module in Java, and in this case, to use one of its built-in methods to preemptively clear the cache.

Comment: Can each PGraphics be moved/translated independently without repainting/resetting the background?